# Stop capturing after "n" full stops

Tags: python, regex

I am in need of regex which can capture till specified number of full stopd after a particular word.

Consider this text:

> Stack Overflow
>
> It is great website. It works very well.Lot of people help each
>    other.
>
> I love it.

I want my regex to stop capturing after it has encountered **2/3/4** (according to my need in different scenarios) full stops after the **Stack Overflow** word.

**My Regex** captures as many as it can get:

```
p = r'((\bStack Overflow\b)\s*.*(?=\.))'
lst = re.findall(p, text, re.I|re.M|re.DOTALL)
```

If I make it non-greedy and use a regex like below. It stops at 1st full stop.

```
p = r'((\bStack Overflow\b)\s*.*?(?=\.))'
```

I know I have to use `{2}` somewhere but can't figure out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Repeat a group that matches non-period characters, followed by a period character. The number of times you repeat that group will be the number of periods after `Stack Overflow` that get matched. For example:

```
\bStack Overflow\b(?:[^\.]*\.){2}
```

will match 2 sentences (or just periods) after Overflow.

https://regex101.com/r/KYoVjE/1